# android login registration with mysql php android app

Tags: android

I was doing an android application which has a login, signup using MySQL,php and android studio but I had a problem when I was compiling and it was bringing a warning on the method POST but I couldn't figure out what the problem was, the code below is my code and was requesting for any possible solutions that I can use to fix my code

```
package com.example.wandie.clinicapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by WANDIE on 8/1/2016.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();
//THIS IS THE PROBLEM  I HAVE POST shows an error
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.setLogin(true);

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");

                        // Inserting row in users table
                        db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                        // Launch main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your logcat here

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to do call by post method

```
 public static String httpPostRequest(Context context, String url, String data) {
        String response = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            Log.d("RequestManager", url + " ");
            Log.e("data::", " " + data);
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

            data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
                    + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8");


            wr.write(data);
            wr.flush();

            Log.d("post response code", conn.getResponseCode() + " ");

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == 401) {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
                context.sendBroadcast(i);
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            response = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("Error", "error");
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        Log.d("RESPONSE POST", response);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: should i put that method within the same that same class

Comment: yes. or you can also make separate class file for it

Comment: alright let me create the class but this is my log cat